# Appending query params to relative Uri

Tags: c#, uri, uribuilder

I have a relative `uri` as a string, only **sometimes** with query parameters.
For instance  `/?abc`.
My task is to append `l=a` to a query.
I tried to use methods of `Uri` and `UriBuilder`, but it seems both of them do not support relative uris.
Any ideas?